# sphinx how to build index and execute my first query

Tags: mysql, centos, sphinx

I have installed the sphinx 2.9 in my centos, But I am unable to index the search file to make search query in my prebuild database.
Below is my code in sphinx.conf

```
source src1
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = *****
    sql_user        = *********
    sql_pass        = ****
    sql_db          = *****
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT people_id,people_fname \
        FROM people

    sql_attr_uint       = people_id
    sql_attr_uint       = people_fname
}


index test1
{
    source          = src1
    path            = /var/lib/sphinx/test1
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 128M
}
```

Then i run the command  sudo bin/indexer test1 which gives

```
indexing index 'test1'...
WARNING: attribute 'people_id' not found - IGNORING
ERROR: index 'test1': No fields in schema - will not index.
```

So where I am going wrong in this

Comment: Sphinx requires the first column in the sql query to be a document id, so you can't declare it as an attribute.

Comment: And also you have no text fields in your config.

Comment: people_id is primery key for that table, are you talking about this??

Comment: After looking at your config I can't understand what you are trying to search. Sphinx is a full-text search engine. It collects text documents using the query specified in `sql_query` option. In you case it does not contain any text fields. It has only 2 integer attributes declared using `sql_attr_uint`. Your config is illegal for Sphinx.

Comment: Thnx for hank, I am building the application that has very large database so my requirement is to make search through various tables, to be at very small scale i want to check if the search works perfectly, for this I want to make search in people table where user will enter his name in the searchbox and relevant result will be shown as per first name search in the table

Comment: If people_fname, is the column you want to search, it should not be declared as an integer attribute (which is what sql_attr_uint does). As also noted the id shouldnt be listed as a sql_attr_uint either. So **delete** the two sql_attr_uint lines from your config. The first column will automatically be the id. all other columns (unless defined as attribute) will be full-text fields.

Comment: Hi, I have gone through many of tutorial available but no one works for me that always show the errors like " 1 duplicate document id pairs found
" or "attribute 'itemid' not found - IGNORING" or "FATAL: no valid indexes to serve". Can you provide me link of any working example I am using sphinx 2.2.9 release for this